# Where is the official Apache Spark docker repository

Tags: docker, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Does apache spark have their own docker repository? I have searched for it but found all unofficial repos.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=&type=image&image_filter=official

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no official docker image for Apache Spark.

This said, you can always build/create your own using a command line script provided with the project.

> Spark (starting with version 2.3) ships with a Dockerfile that can be used for this purpose, or customized to match an individual application’s needs. It can be found in the kubernetes/dockerfiles/ directory.
>
> Spark also ships with a bin/docker-image-tool.sh script that can be used to build and publish the Docker images to use with the Kubernetes backend.

Example usage is:

```
$ ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my-tag build
$ ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my-tag push
```

Answer (score 1):

The official site would be https://github.com/apache?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=spark&type=&language= 
There are no evidences of spark-docker, altough there are other -dockered solutions.